# Create and use an ArrayList from within a single method?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

Is it possible to create and use an `ArrayList` within a method? I would like to create a temporary stack in the `public int min()` method to track the smallest value. However, the compiler complains about the ArrayList `add()` method: `Cannot resolve method 'add(int)'` I presume that's because I'm trying to run it inside the same method that created the `ArrayList`?

```
import java.util.*;

public class MinStack {
private ArrayList<Integer> data;


public MinStack() {
    data = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}

public void push( int a ) {
    data.add( a );
}

public int pop() {
    if ( data.size() <= 0 ) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    return data.remove( data.size() - 1 );
}

public int size() {
    return data.size();
}

public int min() {
    MinStack smalls = new MinStack();
    int elMin = (data.get((data.size() - 1)));
    smalls.add(elMin);
    while (!data.isEmpty()) {
        if (data.get(data.size() - 1) < elMin)
        elMin = data.get(data.size() - 1);
    }
    return elMin;
}
```

Comment: `push` != `add`.

Comment: smalls.add(elMin); --> smalls.push(elMin);

Comment: Why do you think there could be a restriction about using an `ArrayList`, or anything at all, “within a method”? Besides that, if all you want to use, is pushing and popping, you may use an `ArrayDeque` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You are not calling `add` method on an instance of `Arraylist` but instead you are calling it on an instance of `MinStack` class object which doesn't have `add` method.

You should be calling `push` method instead as it is defined in your class which will call `add` method of the arraylist. Or else define/rename(push) a `method` in `MinStack` class with name `add`

Answer (score 2):

You have used a improper design strategy to implement this class. Their are lots of flows in your implementation and here i am not gonna talk about those. Within you design approach, Instead of calling implemented behavior call `push()` in your class. You are trying to call a method which is not implement in this class called `add()`. If you want to use your implented behaviour within the class, Just call your method as `smalls.push(elMin)` instated of `smalls.add(elMin)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
smalls.add(elMin)
```

is looking for add method of MinStack class. You should call push method to insert elMin in data arrayList.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can do this like below:

```
public int min() {

    if(data.isEmpty())
        throw new RuntimeException("the list is empty...");
    int elMin = data.get(0);
    for(int i : data) {
        if(i < elMin) {
            elMin = i;
        }
    }
    return elMin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Call push method to insert `elMin` in `ArrayList data`.